# The strong-ness of x86 store instruction wrt. SC-DRF?

Tags: c++, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers, stdatomic, memory-model

I read about Herb's atomic<> Weapons talk and had a question about page 42:
[image]

He mentioned that (50:00 in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeLBd2EJLOU)):

> (x86) stores are much stronger than they need to be...

**What I don't understand is**: if the x86 "S" on the chart is a plain store, i.e. `mov`, I don't think it's stronger than SC-DRF because it's only a release store plus total store order (and that's why you need an `xchg` for a SC store). But if it means an SC store, i.e. `xchg`, it should fall on the "fully SC" bar because it's effectively a full barrier. **How should I take this x86 "S"'s strong-ness on the chart?**

([SC-DRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#SC_for_DRF) is a guarantee of Sequentially Consistent execution for Data Race Free programs, as long as they don't use any atomics with orders weaker than `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.  ISO C++ and Java, and other languages, provide this.)

Comment: What is SC-DRF?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it stands for "Sequential Consistency for Data-Race-Free program". You can watch Herb's "atomic<> Weapons" talk for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, he's showing `xchg` there (full barrier and an RMW operation), not just a `mov` store - a plain `mov` would be below the SC-DRF bar because it doesn't provide sequential consistency on its own without `mfence` or other barrier.

Compare ARM64 `stlr` / `ldar` - they can't reorder with each other (not even StoreLoad), but `stlr` *can* reorder with other later operations, except of course other release-store operations, or some fences.  (Like I mentioned in answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204442/does-c11-sequential-consistency-memory-order-forbid-store-buffer-litmus-test/70210898#70210898)).  See also [Does STLR(B) provide sequential consistency on ARM64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67397460/does-stlrb-provide-sequential-consistency-on-arm64) re: interaction with `ldar` for SC vs. `ldapr` for just `acquire` / `release` or `acq_rel`.  Also [Possible orderings with memory_order_seq_cst and memory_order_release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67693687/possible-orderings-with-memory-order-seq-cst-and-memory-order-release) for another example of how AArch64 compiles (without ARMv8.3 LDAPR).

---

**But x86 seq_cst stores drain the store buffer on the spot, even if there is no later seq_cst load, store, or RMW in the same thread**.  This lack of reordering with later non-SC or non-atomic loads/stores is what makes it stronger (and more expensive) than necessary.

Herb Sutter explained this earlier in the video, [at around 36:00](https://youtu.be/KeLBd2EJLOU?t=2161).  He points out `xchg` is stronger than necessary, not just an SC-release that can one-way reorder with later non-SC operations.  "**So what we have here, is overkill.  Much stronger than is necessary**" at 36:30

(Side note: right around 36:00, he mis-spoke: he said "we're not going to use these first 3 guarantees" (that x86 doesn't reorder loads with loads or stores with stores, or stores with older loads).  But those guarantees are why SC load can be just a plain `mov`.  [Same for acq/rel being just plain `mov` for both load and store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314179/c-how-is-release-and-acquire-achieved-on-x86-only-using-mov).  That's why as he says, `lfence` and `sfence` are irrelevant for std::atomic.)

---

So anyway, ARM64 can hit the sweet spot with no extra barrier instructions, being exactly strong enough for seq_cst but no stronger.  (ARMv8.3 with `ldapr` is slightly stronger than `acq_rel` requires, e.g. ARM64 still forbids IRIW reordering, but [only a few machines can do that in practice, notably POWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see/50679223#50679223))

Other ISAs with both L and S below the bar need extra barriers as part of their seq_cst load and seq_cst store recipes ([https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I get the "they are stronger than they need to be" part. My last confusion is that if we were talking about `xchg`, wouldn't it be on the very top, i.e., fully SC, of the chart?

Comment: @zanmato: Yeah, I don't know why x86 `xchg` wouldn't right up there with the fence at the top, fully SC.  Good point.  It's exactly as strong as what most C++ implementations use for `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)`, a `lock addl $0, (%rsp)`.   ([xchg is equivalent to mfence for everything except weakly-ordered movntdqa loads from WC memory on some microarchitectures](//stackoverflow.com/q/40409297).   But std:atomic leaves it up to the programmer to manually sfence or mfence after using weakly-ordered stores, and many implementations do use a locked op, not mfence, for atomic_thread_fence).

Comment: Thank you Peter. Great answer and follow-up, as always!